# How to add a class to a group of elements in an array

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I want to add the class ".mlft" to a specifics elements in an array

```
    const divSubMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-collapse'); // 209 elements have the array
    let divSubmenuarray = divSubMenu [0, 166, 187, 205, 208]; // i need to add the class for these specific elements 
for (j = 0; j < divSubmenuarray.length; i++){
    function addMargin(){
        divSubmenuarray.classList.add('mlft')
    }
    addMargin();
    console.log(divSubmenuarray);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid syntax. Put the indexes to access in an array and loop over that instead.

```js
const divSubMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-collapse');
for (const i of [0, 166, 187, 205, 208]) {
    divSubMenu[i].classList.add('mlft');
}
```